# Including 'Name' in IdentityModels.cs for New Registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My web application is ASP.NET MVC5 and I am using VS Express 2013.2 for Web. My problem is in registering a new account. For some reason an error is being returned from AccountController.cs saying that 'Name cannot be null or empty' even though it contains the name when I trace through it.

**IdentityModels.cs:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string StateProvince { get; set; }
    public string StateProvinceCode { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

**RequestAccount.cshtml:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
</div>
```

**AccountViewModels.cs:**

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> RequestAccount(RequestAccountViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { 
                //UserName = model.UserName,
                Email = model.Email,
                Name = model.Name,
                Company = model.Company,
                Phone = model.Phone,
                CountryCode = model.CountryCode,
                StateProvince = model.StateProvince,
                StateProvinceCode = model.StateProvinceCode,
                Language = model.Language };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

When I trace through RequestAccount I can see that model.Name contains "John Doe", but `result.Succeeded` always returns `false` with an error of `Name cannot be null or empty`. I don't see why there is an error of Name being empty when I can clearly see it is not...

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong or how I can test further to determine the problem?

I've seen screen captures included in posts here on SO and I created one of Locals in debug, but I don't see how to include it in my question. Definitely, `model.Name = "John Doe"` and `user.Name = "John Doe"`. :S

Comment: Why is UserName = model.UserName commented out? I think this needs to be set. It is the only field set on ApplicationUser in http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: My project specs do not ask the user for a username. Authentication is changed from username/password to email/password. Is it wrong to comment out UserName?

Comment: Try setting Username = model.Email, then the username will be their email as per the spec. See whether this solves your issue.

Comment: I will do this. Thx. Btw, I updated VS 2013.1 to VS 2013.2 today. Part of the update instructions were to update, then create a new ASP.NET web application. When I ran that default application and clicked Login, the form was Email Address/Password instead of Username/Password. I'll try your suggestion. Maybe the error message I'm getting is erroneous in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set Username in ApplicationUser.

As your spec states that they should be using their email to log in set

```
Username = model.Email
```

Comment: Good call. So, the error of `Name cannot be null or empty` is erroneous? If it would have been `UserName cannot be null or empty` I would have had a good idea what was wrong... Thx again.